# "Slideable" backpack buckles

Tags: gear, backpacks

How are these "slideable" backpack buckles called? I am asking because I want to get a replacement. The backpack is a "[Millican Fraser 32L](https://www.homeofmillican.com/collections/fraser-the-rucksack-32l)" but the type of buckle should not be exclusive to this specific backpack.
[image]

*** Updated pictures ***

Not identified:
[image]

"Buckle hook":
[image]

Comment: I can't really see the buckle very well in that photo, but if you look through the buckles for sale on websites that sell supplies for DIY outdoor gear, you may be able to identify it. Here are a few sites to get you started: [Ripstop by the Roll](https://ripstopbytheroll.com/collections/plastic-hardware), [DIY Gear Supply](https://diygearsupply.com/product-category/plastic-hardware/), [Shelby Outdoor](https://www.shelbyoutdoor.com/?cPath=402_415), [Outdoor Wilderness Fabrics, Inc](https://www.owfinc.com/Metal-Hardware/departments/328/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I added better photographs of the buckles! ... One seems to be called "buckle hook" ... but the other?

Comment: The closeup photos are helpful. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything similar at any of my usual backpack hardware suppliers, as well as all the ones I could find by googling. But I've definitely seen hardware like that, so it's not some weird fringe product. Can you add some more details to your question, like the brand of the bag, the width of the webbing, what part of the world you bought it in, and what kind of activities it's meant for?

Comment: Does the first one work like a "pass through buckle"?  https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+through+buckle

Comment: @DaveX Yes, that's it!

Comment: extremtextil.de has the g-buckles, in several sizes: https://www.extremtextil.de/en/search?sSearch=g-buckle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing the model and seller for this backpack was the key. From their website, I found this info about the buckles:

> BUCKLES (COMPONENTS)
> We use aluminium buckles on all our Maverick bags. These are tough enough to withstand an average force of around 122 kgf (kilogram force). The aluminium is anodized, which provides a weather resistant surface without tarnishing, and the anodized trims we use are non-toxic and contain no nickel.

So now we know the buckles are anodized aluminum (or aluminium). By adding that to my search term, I finally started getting some similar hits. Once I found a similar-looking buckle, I was able to find out the term for that shape of buckle.

The second one is a "G hook buckle." Some G hook buckles are flat, and therefore reversible. Others are slightly curved or otherwise shaped, which means they can only be used in one orientation. That type usually has two versions, one where the hook will point to the right, and one where the hook will point to the left. Yours looks like it's probably the flat kind, but I would need to handle it to be sure. You can probably substitute any version that fits the same size of webbing. Here are a few different product listings, purely as examples. It's quite easy to find other product listings for G hook buckles.

[image] [source](https://www.globalsources.com/Bag-buckle/metal-alloy-G-hook-buckle-1154641681p.htm#1154641681)

[image] [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088P8PH7V))

[image] [source](https://milspecmonkey.com/store/hardware-diy/369-itw-g-hook-flat.html)

---

The first buckle is not a common style, and there's no consistent naming convention for it, which makes it difficult to find for sale.

A similar buckle is used on the [VTAC Scuffle belt](https://www.vikingtactics.com/product-p/50000.htm):

[image] [source](https://www.vikingtactics.com/product-p/50000.htm)

They don't sell the buckle separately, so you'd have to buy a whole belt. The product description calls it a "smooth front buckle" with an "ingenious interlocking buckle design." "Interlocking belt buckle" as a search term doesn't narrow it down very much.

The British military uses an interlocking quick release belt buckle:

[image] [source](https://www.military.direct/products/olive-green-quick-release-buckle)

There are other interlocking belt buckles, for example:

[image] [source](https://www.oyo-7.top/ProductDetail.aspx?iid=59731438&pr=29.99)

As DaveX pointed out, similar types of buckles are used on safety harnesses. In that context, they're called either "mating buckles" or "pass through buckles." Those buckles are difficult to find separately from their harnesses.
You can find some of them in bulk quantities on Alibaba, in the [Buckles & Adjusters section](https://jsstamping.en.alibaba.com/productgrouplist-804155972/Buckles_Adjusters.html). Many of the items on this page require a minimum purchase of 100 or even 1000, but there are a few with a minimum of 10, which which makes them somewhat reasonable for repairing a single backpack (usually 10 will cost less than $10, not including shipping). I'm including the product names and links to the listings below; even if the links go dead, the product names may be useful for finding similar items. As you can see, they don't have a consistent naming convention for these buckles.

- ["New product safety adjustable metal side release buckle"](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-product-safety-adjustable-metal-side_60631182364.html)
- [Climbing Carabiner Tool Customized Black Camping Steel Buckle](https://jsstamping.en.alibaba.com/product/1600113987771-804155972/Climbing_Carabiner_Tool_Customized_Black_Camping_Steel_Buckle.html?spm=a2700.shop_pl.41413.32.6e8433138mr6V6) (this product is only half the entire buckle assembly)

  [image]
- [Hot sale quick release buckle for fall protection as well as bags and luggages](https://jsstamping.en.alibaba.com/product/1600116947934-804155972/Hot_sale_quick_release_buckle_for_fall_protection_as_well_as_bags_and_luggages.html?spm=a2700.shop_pl.41413.40.6e8433138mr6V6)
  [image]

The two parts of this buckle can be named and purchased individually, but it would be tricky to find ones that are compatible with each other in this combination. The piece on the right is a tri-glide

[image]

The piece on the left is a webbing reducer

[image]

You can easily find the two separate parts using the terms "tri-glide" and "webbing reducer." These types of parts are sized by their interior dimensions (IE, what size of webbing fits into them), not by their exterior dimensions. You would need to know the exterior dimensions of the tri-glide to know if it would fit easily through the larger hole in the webbing reducer. Realistically, you'd need to actually assemble and test multiple combinations to find one that functions well.

Comment: From the googling around, I think they are often used on safety harnesses, and called buckles are "Mating Buckles" if you have to twist them sideways to get them through, or a "Pass Through Buckle" if there's a bit of a keyway to help get them through.

Comment: @DaveX I looked at those two terms after you pointed them out. So far I've *only* found mating/pass-through buckles on safety harnesses. I couldn't even find them for sale as replacements for safety harnesses, and I suspect that if they were available they'd be too expensive for use on a backpack, since safety harnesses have to be rated to hold the weight of a person who could die if the buckle failed. So while we have a name for this type of buckle, it's not useful for getting a replacement. (At least as far as I could see.)

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much for your great answer! It helps me a lot :) Fantastic!

Comment: @Stücke Glad it helps. I also realized the two-piece interlocking buckle could be purchased as separate parts, so I added the names of those parts at the end. Could be tricky to find parts that fit together well, though.

Comment: @Stücke It's also worth noting that the Millican website says they will do repairs and/or provide advice on DIY repairs. So if you contact them they may provide you with replacement buckles (probably for a price, unless yours failed due to poor construction and/or they have exceptionally good customer service).

Comment: @csk -- This article https://www.fallprotectionpros.com/blogs/fall-protection-blog/the-mystery-of-safety-harness-buckles compares the different buckles on safety harnesses, and said they were the cheap option for compliance.  Maybe harness companies find them easier to design & build as needed and test them as a system with the webbing, versus sourcing them external components.

Comment: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-product-safety-adjustable-metal-side_60631182364.html  -- This "quick release buckle for fall protection" on offer from Alibaba / Jinsong stamping seems much like the steel pass-through and mating buckles on safety harnesses. --these are good too: https://jsstamping.en.alibaba.com/productgrouplist-804155972/Buckles_Adjusters.html

Comment: @DaveX Excellent find. I added your links to my answer.

Comment: I have a buckle similar to the one in the final photos in your answer on the hip belt of my Haglöfs Lex 110 backpack ([Shelby calls them easy release buckles](https://www.shelbyoutdoor.com/product_info.php?cPath=402_415_64_537&products_id=1844)), and I wish all large backbacks had them on the hip belt. My standard side release buckles always end up breaking (and may be hard to open when my hands are very cold). Pity the superior buckle type is rarely used and hard to find.